# Two meshes are merged as one object in Object Mode, but vertices are still like two objects in edit mode

Tags: mesh, vertices

as you can see on Imgur, I merged two meshes in Object Mode, but in Edit Mode, the vertices still look like two different objects.

There is even screen of my model data for you to get to the bigger picture.

Any advices?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is how it works.  Joining (merging) objects doesn't affect the meshes other than to place them both in the same object.  You can see similar behavior if you add a cube when you're in edit mode.  The cube is still independent of whatever mesh was already there.  Now you have to go into edit mode and bridge edge loops, in this case, to join the two meshes

Comment: to add to Marty's comment, if you want the meshes to merge you need to boolean them, you can try it in Edit mode: Select one of your meshes, and press Ctrl F > Boolean, then choose Union in the Operator box (bottom left of your 3D view)